# How to show loading message in mashup Qlik Sense

Tags: javascript, qliksense, mashup, hypercube

im trying to show a loading message when mashup app is obtaining data from Qlik server but i don't get good result with my approach.

My approach is something like that:

First i get de current selections from getLists method and when selections change show the loading message. Then in the hypercube callback at the end of this method i hide the loading message.

The code is something like that:

In getList Method

```
app.getList("CurrentSelections", function (reply) {
    if(selection_change()){
        show_loading_message();
    }
});
```

In every HyperCube:

```
app.createCube(config_cube, function (reply) {
    //do stuff with reply data
     hide_loading_message();
});
```

This code is inside of every hypercube in the panel and hide loading message() method wait for the finish of the execution of every cube like of join() method in python multiprocess package.

But my problem is getList and app.createCube method  are asynchronous them sometimes the loading message is active after the execution of createcube method and dont back hide the message again.

Someone know how to improve this problem, I need to show the loading message because I'm working with large dataset and qlik sense engine is delayed to give the response data

Thank you!